# Applying same logic on all the ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

The following implementation works on a single ViewController. However, I want to apply same logic all the other ViewControllers as well.

Rather than repeating(copy-paste) the same code again and again in each of the ViewController, what would be a good approach?

**ViewControllerA**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 //common
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func willEnterForeground() {
 if (expired()){
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
 }
}
```

Comment: Subclasses. That's what subclasses are for. This absolutely should not be applied to *all* UIViewControllers, since many of those are provided by Apple, and it would be very bad if you modified their `viewDidLoad` this way. But for every one of *your* view controllers, you just need to add this behavior as a superclass.

Comment: @RobNapier, would you mind to illustrate your proposed solution as an answer please?

Comment: Seriously? Creating a parent class and subclasses is a fundamental technique in iOS development (and to all object-oriented development for that matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclasses. That's what subclasses are for. This absolutely should not be applied to all UIViewControllers, since many of those are provided by Apple, and it would be very bad if you modified their viewDidLoad this way. But for every one of *your* view controllers, you just need to add this behavior as a superclass.

To create a subclass like this, you'd make an intermediate view controller type:

```
class ForegroundPoppingViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func willEnterForeground() {
        if (expired()){
            navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

And then for all the view controller you want to have this behavior, you would subclass:

```
class MyViewController: ForegroundPoppingViewController { ... }
```

If MyViewController has its own `viewDidLoad`, you'd chain that to its superclass, just like in any other subclass:

```
class MyViewController: ForegroundPoppingViewController { 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ... any other behaviors ...
    }
}
```

This would not apply to Apple view controllers, such as UIDocumentBrowserViewController, but it shouldn't. That may not give valid behavior. You would need to decide on the proper behavior depending on what view controller you're presenting.

Also, as a general rule, you should observe notifications in `viewDidAppear` (or willAppear) and remove notification observations in `viewWillDisappear` (or didDisappear). You *usually* do not want notifications firing on view controllers that are not currently onscreen.

That said, for this particular problem, I probably would recommend moving this logic to a "presenter" type coordinator, or even a UINavigationController subclass. As written, this may call `popToRootViewController` many times (since many view controllers may exist at the same time), which may lead to animation glitches.

But for the general question of how to add functionality to view controllers, this is how you would do it.

Comment: but I have more things in the `viewDidLoad()` which I removed to make question simplifier. As I see that you used `viewDidLoad()` as a subclass. How would I handle that scenario?

Comment: I'm not quite certain what you mean here. If there are more things in `viewDidLoad`, you'd just include those things. Is there something deeper to your question?

Comment: `NotificationCenter` in the `viewDidLoad()` and its `@objc` method are common.

Comment: So in those subclasses, you'd called `super.viewDidLoad()` to get the behavior of ForegroundPoppingViewController, which itself calls `super.viewDidLoad()` to get the behavior of UIViewController.

Comment: do you have any idea for the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707438/rootviewcontroller-of-the-keywindow-instead-of-poptorootviewcontroller which is follow up question that you answered here?